# Value of type 'string' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of byte'

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get an application to find its current path/directory, and then use that to install a zip file then extract it into the specified location. (SelFolder)

```
Dim progDirectory As String

Public Sub Install()
    progDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", progDirectory, False)
    Unzip(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", SelFolder)
End Sub
```

The error is where progDirectory is when using the WriteAllBytes Command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: The second argument of WriteAllBytes should be the bytes you're trying to write. You're currently passing in a string... what is the point of WriteAllBytes? i.e what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: The zip file is written to a directory that is chosen by the user, then unzipped, and deleted. Works if I use My.Resources.Resource code. But i want it separate of the program.

Comment: Why not just use [`System.IO.File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) method to copy the zip file to the user selected directory?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are misunderstanding how to use `WriteAllBytes`.

The second parameter of [`FileSystem.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writeallbytes.aspx) is the data to write (`byte[] data`). You're passing a string that indicates a path to a file instead, that's why you get this error.

Comment: So how would I change this to fix the issue? Or rather, how might I convert the string into a byte array?

Comment: Are you trying to write `progDirectory` to your file? Take into account that this is not the way to create a zip file, but if the only thing you want is converting `progDirectory` to byte array, that could be easily done.

Comment: I will distribute the .exe and the .zip file, so I want to obtain the location of the .exe file. (or the .zip if possible)

If I use:
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", My.Resources.Resource, False) it works fine.

Comment: @user2580915: What I'm trying to say is that you don't write plain bytes to a zip file. You're supposed to compress the information. You have many options to create zip files out there.

Comment: I'm not creating a .zip file. I'm trying to find the location of it and then unzip and install from their. It works fine if the location is My.Resources.Resource

Comment: @user2580915: but `WriteAllBytes` writes information to the zip file, I'm honestly very confused. Could you clarify what do you think `WriteAllBytes` does?

Comment: I assumed it writes the file to the directory chosen, as that is what it did. Currently, the zip in the program resources is written to the directory, it is then unzipped and deleted. It works with this code, but I want the zip separate from the program resources.

Comment: @user2580915 - What exactly is My.Resources.Resource?  My guess is that is is not just a string, but probably a file.  Under what category in your resources is it listed?